# Unifying tus uploads with Rails API using Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, file-upload, shrine

I recently made a Rails 5 API that uses Shrine for file attachments (videos attached to a model named Upload). The user would send a POST request with the file to `hostname.com/api/uploads` and a new Upload object would be added to the database.

I have been following tutorials online for adding tus compatibility to Shrine using `tus-ruby-server` and `tus-js-client` and they all indicate that there is a separate endpoint (say `hostname.com/files`) that is used to upload files using tus. Is there any way to unify this endpoint with the endpoint my API app already had for uploading files?

Comment: Tus-ruby-server is an encapsulated Rack application, in which way would you like to unify tus-ruby-server's endpoints with your app's endpoint?

Comment: @janko-m in the sense that I can POST to my API endpoint to have the file uploaded to a certain folder and its information saved in the database, and I can use `tus-js-client` to have the file uploaded to a different folder without saving any records to the database. Is there any way to have it so I can use `tus-js-client` to upload the file to the same folder that my API would save it in, and also save its record in the database? I got a working example running using tutorials, but the biggest problem is that no database record is created.

Comment: That is a good point, unfortunately at the moment `tus-ruby-server` pretty-much just acts as a black-box Rack endpoint, without the possibility to forward "tus requests" to the main app. I should probably add some kind of hooks, though notice that since `Tus::Server` is a Roda app you can use Roda's `hooks` plugin which allows you to specify `before` and `after` blocks. http://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/Hooks.html

Comment: @janko-m thanks, I'll check it out!